# Multiclass classification with Random Forest in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest, decision-tree, apache-spark-mllib, multilabel-classification

[The Apache Spark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html#random-forests) (1.4.0) promises that Random Forest (the same promise is for decision trees) can be extended to multiclass classification setting. However, I can't find any way to reach this using RandomForestModel API:

```
randomForestModel.predict
```

Could you please provide a right way how to do that, if it's really possible in 1.4.0 version?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I've found it in an experimental package (ml): org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel

and transform should be used instead of predict:

```
RandomForestClassificationModel.transform
```